# Slim route with parameter not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I'm trying to setup [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) for me application i've got issue that route with parameters not working.

This is my `index.php`

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();


// GET route
$app->get('/', function () {
    print "hello";
});



$app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {
    print $id;
});

$app->run();
```

---

This is the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Request to `/` works fine, but if I pass `/books/1` it returns **[404] not found**

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: are you getting an especific error/log of the error, if that is the case include it in the question

Comment: @MikeRockett yes i have  'AllowOverride all' in apache config

Comment: @MauricioGracia i don't get any specific error just 404 page not found

Comment: `AllowOverride All` does not mean that `mod_rewrite` is enabled - they have nothing to do with one another. Check if `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: @MikeRockett it's uncommented

Answer (score 0):

Man your mod_rewrite is not enable in apache.For enable mod_rewrite follow this.Reference http://www.kingpabel.com/apache-mod-rewrite/

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

//enable mod rewrite
a2enmod rewrite

//restart apache
service apache2 restart
```